# Using a Regex Pattern that finds Abbrevations

Tags: regex

I am looking through volumes of data and need to identify certain patterns one of which is abbreviations. The basic rules to identify them in the content I am going through is

- They are all is capital letters.
- They are separated by dots.
- They may be one or more alphabets
- They may or may not end with a dot.
- I am looking at individual words therefore looking for multiple occurrences in the string is not required.

Examples
U.S., U.S, U.S.S.R., V.

Can someone help construct a regex search pattern for me?

Many thanks
MS

Comment: ([A-Z](\.))+ I guess that helps

Comment: "one or more alphabets", you mean like the Cyrillic alphabet? The Greek alphabet?

Comment: Note that the accepted answer doesn't do what the OP was asking for. The question is about "identifying" a pattern in context, that one just "validates" it (much simpler task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([A-Z]\.)*[A-Z]\.?$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qU8vK1/3)

Comment: this won't do for U.S. Also I matches something like this: US.

Comment: Requirement state that chars are separated by '.'. so I guess he is looking for a specific ones.

Comment: Anubhava, that matches any words written in capital letters like USSR and US and US. The problem with that is that certain portions of the text contain words in CAPITAL like a header if you like and matching US. is a problem for a word that ends with a dot.

Comment: Oh btw, I would get rid of that $ sign at the end.

Comment: A few more iterations and you'll end up with the same regex as in my answer ;)

Comment: @nafas: Getting rid of `$` in the end will make it match `U` in `USSR`.

Comment: Thanks anubhava the updated one is correct and works for me. It also matches single alphabets with no following dots but otherwise is works fine.

Comment: Thanks @MWS: Glad to know it worked. I think you did mention that ending dot is optional.

Comment: @anubhava but what if there are more than one in a single line,

Comment: @nafas: As you can see it matches `U.S.S.R` as well as `U.S.S.R.` both with multiple dots.

Comment: @anubhava Try the following example "U.S.S.R. U.R", it should match U.S.S.R and U.R, but since $ sign is there, it won't match any of them

Comment: @anubhava I would suggest this: **\b([A-Z]\.)*[A-Z]\.?\b**  however, it doesn't capture some of the dots.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
\b(?:\p{Lu}\.)*\p{Lu}\b\.?
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xX5yX0/2)

I've used `\p{Lu}` (unicode uppercase letters) since you want to match any alphabet.

If you can't make `\b` unicode aware in your dialect, here's an alternative:

```
(?<!\p{L})(?:\p{Lu}\.)*\p{Lu}(?!\p{L})\.?
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas, this one works too, gives the same results as the one by Anubhava.

Comment: But it matches `U-` also.

Comment: While I'm personally a big fan of i18n, this attempt looks a bit naïve to me. If you're matching any letter, you have to make sure all letters are from the same script. Something like `R.Σ.Я.` would be hardly acceptable. Also, AFAIK `\b` is not unicode-aware in some dialects.

Comment: @anubhava I made the regex match abbreviations in the middle of strings. Since it's not required by the asker, you can wrap it in `^`...`$` and it won't match `U-` anymore.

Comment: @georg You're right but I don't think the "same script" requirement is something that's doable with regex. As for `\b`, I'll write an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. it also matches the ending dots.

```
 \b([A-Z]\.)*[A-Z]\b\.?
```